# How to add the scroll bar for FullCalendar.js for mobile devices?

Tags: css, fullcalendar

I am currently using FullCalendar.js which has many events where the scroll bar appears on the desktop version of the page. However, when I go the mobile version or tablet version of the page, the scroll bar is non-existent and it blows up the page.

I am currently using media queries and yet it still does not display the scroll bar.

**UPDATE:**

This is the css I am using but does not work

CSS code:

```
@media(max-width:480px){
    .fc-scroller{
        overflow-x:hidden !important;
        overflow-y: scroll !important;
        height:100px !important
    }
```

Comment: Are you using `overflow: scroll`? Some code would be helpful...

Comment: Yes I am using that. Here is what I am doing to call it

Comment: @LucasWatson Code has been provided

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? FullCalendar scroll works on everything but iOS for me.